# System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Byte[]'.'

Tags: c#, base64

i am trying to convert the azure blob file that is inserted in azure sql table to base64 string, but before that when i try to read the data from data reader through bytes[] i am getting the following error "System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Byte[]'.'" from the below code which i tried and blocked here

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage;
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob;
using System.Text.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

namespace FunctionApp2
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get","post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            try
            {
                string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
                var json = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonElement>(requestBody);

                string id = json.GetProperty("DocumentID").GetString();

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
                {
                    return new BadRequestObjectResult("Please provide id");
                }

                string connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SqlConnectionString");

                using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    await connection.OpenAsync();
                    string query = $"select DocumentTitle from DocMeta where DocumentID = '" + id + "'";
                    using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query,connection))
                    {
                        using(SqlDataReader reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
                        {
                            if(await reader.ReadAsync())
                            {
                                byte[] fileData  = (byte[])reader["DocumentTitle"];
                                //byte[] fileData = Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes("DocumentTitle");

                                string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(fileData);

                                dynamic response = new
                                {
                                    id = id,
                                    content = base64String
                                };

                                return new OkObjectResult(response);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                return new NotFoundObjectResult($"Document with DocumentID '{id}' not found.");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                log.LogError(ex.Message);
                return new StatusCodeResult(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
            }
        }

        private static Task<string> ConfigSettings(string v)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, the SQL string concatenation. The vulnerability, it burns us!

Comment: Oh, but is the byte data really in the "DocumentTitle" field? That seems wrong. A title is usually a shorter string. There's probably a field named DocumentData or similar you want instead.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn *"Nasty developers twisted it, it freezes, take it off! Agh gollum"*

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    await connection.OpenAsync();
    string query = $"select DocumentTitle from DocMeta where DocumentID = '" + id + "'";
    using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query,connection))
    {
        using(SqlDataReader reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
        {
            if(await reader.ReadAsync())
            {
                byte[] fileData  = (byte[])reader["DocumentTitle"];
```

Should look like this:

```
string query = "select DocumentData from DocMeta where DocumentID = @DocID";

byte[] fileData = null;
using(var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using(var command = new SqlCommand(query,connection))
{
    command.Parameters.Add("@DocID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;
    await connection.OpenAsync();
    fileData = (byte[])(await command.ExecuteScalarAsync());
}

if (fileData is object)
{
```

Note the different column name (I had to guess, but you should be able to get the right one), the use of query parameters, the reduced indentation in the code, and the use of `ExecuteScalar()` when we only need one field from one row.

If it were me, I'd also invert that last `if()` conditional (`if (fileData == null)`) to move up the "not found" code and act as a guard clause, so I could close out the block right away. This reduces another level of nesting for the main part of the code (no `else` block needed, as the new `if()` block uses `return`) as well as reducing vertical scrolling for reading the current `else` block.